# .NET Core MailKit SMTP AUTH LOGIN as local linux account

Tags: c#, linux, smtp, postfix-mta, mailkit

I use MailKit library to send mail from ASP.NET Core application. I also tried to avoid MailKit library and use TcpClient directly to send commands to SMTP server (to ensure that library is not a problem). Postfix SMTP server is located on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 server where web application is also being hosted.

When I test application locally (on Windows machine) MailKit successfully authenticates and E-mail is being sent. However, when I run application on Linux Ubuntu authentication fails (same server, port, username and password). When I examine log of communication with the server, problem is obvious - when app is being run on Linux server, application sends root user as username to the SMTP server. I have not specified that as username to be send.

Is there any automatic rule for Postfix to authenticate users? Is there need for any additional Postfix configuration?

(I've changed original usernames and passwords).

Windows Server ...

```
C: AUTH LOGIN
S: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
C: dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbQ==
S: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
C: dGVzdHBhc3N3b3JkCg==
S: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
```

Linux Ubuntu Server ...

```
C: AUTH LOGIN
S: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
C: cm9vdA==
S: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
C: dGVzdHBhc3N3b3JkCg==
S: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
```

Comment: How are you authenticating using MailKit? Are you passing it `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be somehow passing the wrong username string to MailKit because MailKit only uses whatever string you give to it as the username string. It doesn't have any logic to try and get the system username or anything like that.

Are you using the `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`? e.g.:

```
client.Authenticate (CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);
```

If so, that's the problem (and has nothing to do with MailKit).

Comment: I am always sending credentials from configuration.  var credentials = new NetworkCredential(_configuration["User"].ToString(), _configuration["Password"].ToString());  
 SaslMechanismLogin mechanism = new SaslMechanismLogin(credentials);  
 await client.AuthenticateAsync(mechanism);

Comment: And what is the value of `_configuration["User"].ToString()`? Is it correct on the Ubuntu Linux machine? I doubt it.

Comment: You need to figure out where that value gets set or loaded from and fix that code to get the correct value.

Comment: Checked once again. Value is E-mail address which I regularly use to authenticate with SMTP server and which works when I run app on Windows ... This is not a problem of MailKit, because problem occurs even if I send commands directly to server by using TcpClient.

Comment: MailKit is using `credentials.UserName`. You can see that it does here: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/MailKit/Security/SaslMechanismLogin.cs#L277 - make sure that `credentials.UserName` is correct on the Ubuntu Linux machine. I guarantee that it is not correct.

Comment: You are right! Value of User key in configuration dictionary has different value on Ubuntu! Thank you very much!

Comment: I am facing a different issue in ASP.Net Core application @jstedfast. My SMTP server is located in a unix server. While using smtp.gmail.com as host on my local machine, mail sends fine, but on staging server, it emits 
`"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25"` error. What could possibly go wrong? I tried connection to the mail server from the staging machine and it is connecting fine!

Comment: You should probably ask this question on the sister site that deals with network admin questions, but you probably have a firewall or something that is blocking the connection.